# Prove that if $X \subset [a,b]$ isn't a measure-zero set, then there exists $\varepsilon >0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Please, check my solution to this problem:

"Prove that if $X \subset [a,b]$ isn't a measure-zero set, then there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that, for every partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, the sum of the lenghts of the intervals of $P$ which contain points of $X$ is greater than $\varepsilon$".

Solution:

Let $X \subset [a,b]$ be a non measure-zero set. Then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and an enumerable family of open intervals $I_1,...,I_n,...$ such that $X \subset I_1 \cup ... \cup I_n \cup ...$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |I_i|\ge \varepsilon$.

Without lost of generality, We can supose $I_1 \cup ... \cup I_n \cup ... \subset [a,b]$. In such a case, the points $a$, $b$ and the extremities of the intervals $I_1,...,I_n,...$ form a partition of $[a,b]$. By construction, the intervals of this partition which contain points of $x$ have length $ \ge \varepsilon$.
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: You need to explain why the existence of $\epsilon$ is justified. (Second sentence in the solution.) It's also unclear why the given intervals form a partition of $P$. The argument can be simplified: Assume that such a partition exists, and find a lower bound for the measure in question by using the fact that $X$ has positive measure.